# Aplicação sem acesso ao Banco de Dados após publicação no Azure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, microsoft-azure

Publiquei uma aplicação Asp.Net Core 2.1 no Azure, efetuei as Migrations, o banco e tabelas foram criadas normalmente, consigo ver toda a estrutura do banco pelo VS, mas a aplicação não acessa o banco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?

Link da aplicação: https://grifo.azurewebsites.net/

**OBS: A mesma aplicação em ambiente de desenvolvimento acessa o banco local e funciona perfeitamente**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi simples. Apesar de subir os arquivos de configurações com a connectionString e as migrações, foi necessário efetuar uma update desse arquivos, via FTP (sem a publicação automática do VS) com a connectionString do servidor do Azure.